# Android backbutton override issue in 4.4.2

Tags: android, overriding, native, back-button

I want to ask about back button override functionally.
I am using this approach.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  {

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

It works fine all Android platforms but its not working fine on Anroird 4.4.2

How can I implement backbutton override in Android 4.4.2?

Comment: Override onBackPressed() method inside the activity

Comment: Back Button is meant to take you back to the previous activity. why clear the backstack. See navigation guidelines in the docs

Comment: I am not understand it, can you please give me any example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hi why dont you use onBackPressed()

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Try this. and let me know the feedback's.

Comment: kindly give up for the answer if my answer is solved your expectation.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
//Your code
}
```

**Don't call the super in it because it will finish your activity.**